# More concise log on Redis startup

Tags: redis

As I use Redis to start up with a bunch of other processes via Foreman, I find its output on startup quite verbose.

Redis writes more than twice the number of lines to stdout than any other process in my Procfile, mainly because of the ASCII art that gets printed to the log.

Is there a (startup) option to keep the log more concise, for example by turning off the output of the logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: If you have redis version 4.0 or higher you can do `redis-server | cat` to trick it into thinking it's not running in a tty.

Original answer:

I've had a quick check in the config docs and you shouldn't be seeing this. Can you maybe check your config file and see if you've set `always-show-logo` to `yes`?

The comment that accompanies it is as follows:

```
# By default Redis shows an ASCII art logo only when started to log to the
# standard output and if the standard output is a TTY. Basically this means
# that normally a logo is displayed only in interactive sessions.
#
# However it is possible to force the pre-4.0 behavior and always show a
# ASCII art logo in startup logs by setting the following option to yes.
```

I guess if you're on a version < 4.0 then that might explain what you're seeing.

Here is the issue/fix from 2014 https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/1935

Comment: Thanks for the quick and informative reply. I don't know why I didn't find this Github issue myself. 
Sadly it can be turned on/off only for non-interactive sessions, as it seems.

Comment: @cseelus `redis-server | cat`?